# android pass a number through onclicklistener

Tags: android, onclick, buttonclick

I am trying to ask a user for 2 numbers x and y. When the user clicks the button it will subtract y from x and give the total. What I would like it to do is save the total, and the next time you click the button, it will subtract y from the total. I know I am not passing the total back through again, but I am not sure where to begin.

```
subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) throws  NumberFormatException {
            if (v == subtract)
            {
            NumberFormat currencyFormatter;
            currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);



                String bString;
                String x = startingmoney.getText().toString();
                String y = submoney.getText().toString ();
                    double total = 0.00;
                    double xm = 0.00;
                    double ym =0.00;

                     try
                      {
                          xm = Double.parseDouble(x);
                      }
                     catch(NumberFormatException n)
                      {
                          xm = 0.00;
                      }
                     try
                     {
                         ym = Double.parseDouble(y);
                     }
                    catch(NumberFormatException n)
                     {
                        ym = 0.00;
                     }




           total = xm -ym;







                bString = currencyFormatter.format(total);
                endmoney.setText(bString);

                tracker.setText("you have entered " + bString +"\n" + tracker.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One possible way is to make the variable "x" and "y" static. This may not meet your requirement, since you may change the value of "x" and "y" dynamically.

Another way is to change the implement of OnClickListener. You can use it as,

```
class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
```

and pass the class (the class which calls "setOnClickListener") to MyOnClickListener, that is, the constructor of MyOnClickListener is like,

```
MyOnClickListener(CLASS clazz){
    this.clazz = clazz;
}
```

And you can do subtraction with clazz.getX() and clazz.getY().